# FB debugger says that my og:image should be larger, even though it is large

Tags: image, facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, image-size

[Check out this result of debugging an article using Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brunstad.org%2Fen%2Fchristian-life%2Fa-changed-man).

It comes up with this warning:

> og:image should be larger. Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500.

But if you open the image displayed in the "og:image"-field below, you can clearly see that the image is big enough - 700x350 px.

This results in Facebook picking random images when I'm publishing articles on my wall.

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit:** Could the problem be caused by my CMS redirecting the url of the image?

Comment: I see the same issue, and note the cargo cult flavor of answers to date. The shorter answer is "Facebook's debugger is defective," and we're looking for workarounds. The meta-question is: how do we get Facebook's attention to fix this defect?

Comment: Facebook's debugger is a poor tool. This one shows the right things on the page: https://coveloping.com/tools/open-graph-tag-tester

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was due to my CMS system redirecting the URL of the image. So the correct image showed up in the Facebook debugger, but FB was probably looking for the image size before the redirection took place, and then it had no size yet.

So I told my CMS not to redirect the URL of my images. How that works depends on what kind of CMS you are using.

Comment: So what did you do about it?

Comment: I told my CMS not to redirect the URL of my images :) How that works depends on what kind of CMS you are using.

Comment: @Chris: Please include the above comment in the answer.

Comment: For me, I had to make the image equal sides i.e. 512x512, and after that it worked immediately. FB probably resizes the image to fit in a 200x200 box (and constrains proportions) - thus, an image of 700x350 will be resized to 200x100 (to small).

Comment: @FredrikJohansson That's so dumb though. All my images are 930 x 523 and all of them have worked perfectly. Just for some dumb reason today it doesn't want to work even though it's the same size and nothing differently was done

Answer (score 26):

Try to add this:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Comment: Works better than anything on the entire Internet!!

Answer (score 13):

First of all you need to upload an image that is more than 200 x 200 (for instance I've uploaded the maximum size that is 1500 x 1500). Some people say that the image width and height should be the same size. I've never took chances to check if it's right or not although.

After updating the image size the problem still exists and you'll need to add certain parameter to the og: image link in order to make Facebook debugger update the cache of the image.

For instance:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://bri.ge/img/brige1.png?t=12345?">
```

This is the parameter: ?t=12345?

Wait for about 5 minutes and the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Anything over 200x200 has worked for me, but if Width and Height aren't the same, it frames the image as a square the size of the smaller dimension, with parts of the longer dimension cut off.

Comment: the "cache busting" ?t=12345 fixed it for me! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

in the meta tags.

Removed that line and it worked, so current tags look like this:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="PUT TITLE HERE" />   
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg"/>
```

Comment: this worked for me too 
removed `<meta property="og:type" content="game" />`
and it worked

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Tried saving as progressive, tried making it square, tried making it bigger, tried cache busting. Nothing worked until I removed the website tag. Thanks!

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  I don't know why, but removing the og:type meta tag stopped that warning for me.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit late, but I had this issue for after creating a new open graph image in photoshop. It didn't make any sense because in the debugger it still displayed the image that was found, which was 359x379. It still complained it was smaller than 200x200, though.

I did not try changing any other header tags, as I did not believe that was the issue.

Instead, I opened photoshop again and saved the image again. I saved it as a JPG at 85% quality -- and the difference was that I used "Progressive" instead of "Optimized". This fixed the issue immediately, although I'm not positive the "Optimized" setting was the issue.

Comment: With FB's consistent irrational og: problems, I feel like we're suddenly all MLB players who swear not changing our socks is what won the last game... that said, I'm about to try this sock on, since nothing else will work.

Comment: this answer save me, currently I was facing the picture is more than 8mb==, but my image is 600++kbs only after I saw your answer, I save it as low setting and it passes the debug, and my thumbnail shows up.

Answer (score 3):

Another issue that could cause this is the use of characters like # in the filename.

Allthough browser will show them correctly, facebook will give an error stateting the img is to small, while infact it isn't able to read it.

So make sure you image filename only uses the standard characters A to z, _, -, 0-9

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still running into this issue, even though facebook's **scraper** correctly scrapes the image of size >= 200x200, wait an hour and go have coffee. Come back and hit debug again and it should be fine. It takes time for facebook to update its stored graph data.

Comment: You can just rescrape again yourself via facebook debugger

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and tried saving as a JPEG with slightly lower quality as another answerer suggested.  Once I'd referenced that and tried again on the debugger page Facebook told me that, again, my image was too small, and instead it would use the **old** image, meaning the one it complained about the first time.

So I simply submitted the same URL once more and it stopped complaining.  Basically it's one debug behind.  Try refreshing the debug and see if it doesn't fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Define og:image:width and og:image:height parameters like @Maria has suggested.

Comment: Please vote for the answer that you found useful instead of submitting a new one

Answer (score 0):

what did i notice when i run  into Scraped URL   is that facebook is not able to see the picture at the same size like in the posts. For instance, copy the url of the picture  which  in Debug is to small, paste in to a browser and  indeed the picture is very small. Now, go to your post, copy the url picture from your post, and paste in to the same  or any browser. Now the size of the picture is big.

Answer (score 0):

If the image url is https:// and Facebook has problems reading your SSL certificate, it will produce this rather unhelpful error message. To test, see if a http:// url for the image works. If it does, your CA certificate may need some tweaking. Try Googling "Curl Error : SSL_CACERT SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Note: Even if your page has no problem displaying with a https protocol, Facebook digs deeper to confirm your identity. I think this is relatively recent. Considering their whole fake news debacle I'm not going to be too upset.

Answer (score -1):

Your website's robots.txt file may be restricting Facebook crawler access to your website. When Facebook robot crawls it, it can't see the file. Upload the image to the root of your website.

The 200x200 pixel rule is important, use 400x400 to get better image quality through compression. Tested with png and jpeg images.

Comment: I think the facebook bot that crawls the website for information is not acting like a robot so it does not care about robots.txt