# facebook recommendation image not display in fb wall "og:image should be larger"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I move all image of my website to amazone s3, when i try to recommendation any link to facebook i got error and image not display to recommendation  popup.

```
<meta name="og:title" content="Found to be Unpopular Among a Portio" />
<meta name="og:description" content="" />
<meta name="og:image" content="http://d2dbcr33josved.cloudfront.net/images/article/1394213386_obamaca.jpg" />
<meta name="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/f-the-population-healthcare-36719" />
<meta name="fb:admins" content="akashdwivedi94" />
```

Comment: Have you looked through the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134090/fb-debugger-says-that-my-ogimage-should-be-larger-even-though-it-is-large

Comment: my image is in amazone s3 and i try to use it in my domain

Comment: Yeah, good, but did you read the answers of the other people who had the same problem, and did you try their suggestions?