# Facebook OpenGraph debugger response 206

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Here is the URL with the 206 response code : http://frenchpoll.fr

I don't understand why I get that : everything is OK with Twitter, Linkedin and Google +, everything is also OK with Google Webmaster Tools.

I don't understand why it tells me that :
" Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image "

The actual image is bigger and the debugger seems to know it
('http://frenchpoll.fr/img/logo_grandformat.png' will be used instead)

URL, title and description are given but it doesn't acknowledge it...

Could you please help me ? :/

Edit :
Someone had the exact same issue described here ->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108829/good-meta-but-wrong-open-graph-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Image is fine now - seems it doesn't like other tags

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

It sees:

```
og:url  http://frenchpoll.fr/?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
og:type website
og:title    webmail http://webmail.ovh.net
og:description  description de votre site
og:updated_time 1396538300
```

Strange. Try: [FB debugger says that my og:image should be larger, even though it is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134090/fb-debugger-says-that-my-ogimage-should-be-larger-even-though-it-is-large)

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with my server provider (OVH) and I tested ?fbrefresh to refresh the tags...
Could it be an issue with my .htaccess ?